# How to build Animated splash screen with Getx?

Tags: flutter, dart, splash-screen, flutter-animation, flutter-getx

I am confused about this. I Don't know how to update the value to animate the image in the splash screen. With the stateful widget class we call `setState(() {});` inside the listener to update the value. But, How do I achieve it with the Getx?

Animation with Stateful Widget :

```
animationInitilization() {
    animationController =
        AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: const Duration(seconds: 2));
    animation =
        CurvedAnimation(parent: animationController, curve: Curves.easeOut);
    animation!.addListener(() {
      setState(() {});
    });
    animationController.forward();
  }
```

Animation with Getx:

Splash Screen :

```
class SplashScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const SplashScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SplashScreenViewModel splashScreenViewModel =
        Get.put(SplashScreenViewModel());
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        fit: StackFit.expand,
        children: [
          Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Image.asset(
                'assets/images/logo.png',
                width: splashScreenViewModel.animation.value * 200,
                height: splashScreenViewModel.animation.value * 200,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Getx Controller :

```
class SplashScreenViewModel extends GetxController
    with GetSingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  late AnimationController animationController;
  late Animation<double> animation;

  @override
  void onInit() {
    animationInitilization();
    super.onInit();
  }

  animationInitilization() {
    animationController =
        AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: const Duration(seconds: 2));
    animation =
        CurvedAnimation(parent: animationController, curve: Curves.easeOut)
            .obs
            .value;
    animation.addListener(() => update());
    animationController.forward();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nice animation for SplashScreen bro.

I recommend using GetBuilder() to make it work properly:

```
class SplashScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const SplashScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: GetBuilder<SplashScreenViewModel>(
        init: SplashScreenViewModel(),
        builder: (controller) {
          return Stack(
            fit: StackFit.expand,
            children: [
              Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Image.asset(
                    'assets/images/logo.png',
                    width: controller.animation.value * 200,
                    height: controller.animation.value * 200,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Compared to the stateful widget, it's very smooth now. Thank you very much.